# IndexError: pop from empty list Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have an existing object but I want to create an object in the nested serializer, unfortunately, I am getting an error while creating object. What I have done so far here:

```
class AppealSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    resolutions = ResolutionSerializer(many=True, allow_null=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Appeal
        fields = ['id', 'appeal_unique_id', 'short_name', 'category', 'dept', 'state', 'appeal_desc', 'location',
                  'address', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'resolutions', 'user']

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        bp_data = validated_data.pop('resolutions', [])
        bps = (instance.resolutions).all()
        bps = list(bps)
        instance.state = validated_data['state']
        instance.save()

        for b_p in bp_data:
            bp = bps.pop(0)
            bp.user = b_p.get('user', bp.user)
            bp.comment = b_p.get('comment', bp.comment)
            bp.is_read = b_p.get('is_read', bp.is_read)
            bp.save()

        return instance
```

here I am going to create many to one object by updating an existing object. with this code, in another project, I can cope with it but it does not work for this project. please if anything is not clear let me know I will try to explain in more detail. The keyword is to create an object by updating an existing object. Thanks in advance

Comment: Doesn't it work to just check the length before? `if len(bps) > 0: bp = bps.pop(0)`

Comment: no because its length equals zero I am creating objects in present objects

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
You have more items to update than there is in your object.
You need to check if there is nothing to update, but still, have items, then you need to create.

```
for b_p in bp_data:
    if len(bps) < 1:
        bp = bps.pop(0)
        bp.user = b_p.get('user', bp.user)
        bp.comment = b_p.get('comment', bp.comment)
        bp.is_read = b_p.get('is_read', bp.is_read)
        bp.save()
    else:
        Appeal.object.create(appeal=instance, **b_p)
```